# Avoid overlapping on seaborn plots

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm making some EDA using pandas and seaborn, this is the code I have to plot the histograms of a group of features:

```
skewed_data =  pd.DataFrame.skew(data)
skewed_features =skewed_data.index

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=len(skewed_features))
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='both', scilimits=(0,0))
for i,skewed_feature in  enumerate(skewed_features):
    g = sns.distplot(data[column])  
    sns.distplot(data[skewed_feature],  ax=axs[i])
```

This is the result I'm getting:

[image]

Is not readable, how can I avoid that issue?

Comment: If you call `plt.tight_layout()` after plotting that will do a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are concerning about the layout of the figures. However, you need to first decide how to represent your data. Here are two choices for your case

(1) Multiple lines in one figure and

(2) Multiple subplots 2x2, each subplot draws one line.

I am not quite familiar with searborn, but the plotting of searborn is based on matplotlib. I could give you some basic ideas.

To archive (1), you can first declare the figure and ax, then add all line to this ax. Example codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# YOUR LOOP, use the ax parameter
for i in range(3)
    sns.distplot(data[i], ax=ax)
```

To archive (2), same as above, but with different number subplots, and put your line in the different subplot.

```
# Four subplots, 2x2
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2)
# YOUR LOOP, use different cell
```

You may check [matplotlib subplots demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html). To do a good visualization is a very tough work. There are so many documents to read. Check the gallery of [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) or [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html) is a good and quick way to understand how some kinds of visualization are implemented.

Thanks.